# Qt, multiple inheritance, wrappers or event filters

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have a few different QGlWidget based display widgets which I need to embed in either an MDI or QDockwidget based app. But I need to handle some of the MDI/Dock specific events (minimize/dock etc) in my display widget

Options are:
Multiply inherit the display widgets from QGlWidget and QMdiSubWindow/QDockWidget. Any issues with multiply inheriting and signals/slots?

Encapsulate the display inside a QMdiSubWindow/QDock derived widget but then I have to wrap all the display's external functions in the Mdi/Dock wrapper widget.

When I make a new window, create a temporary Mdi/Dock widget, connect all the special signals to slots in the display before attaching the display to it and showing it. But this doesn't work for events.

Some QSignalMapper magic where I can receive QMdiSubWindow/QDockWidget specific signals in a QGlWidget

Comment: Qt doesn't support inheriting from QObject twice in the same object, so assuming that QGIWidget is a subclass of QWidget, your first option isn't going to work...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - thanks, I thought it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDI/dock widgets are *containers* for other widgets, so mixing their features with display widgets is not a very nice solution as you end up with a hideous hybrid widget that looks like a container - but cannot contain anything.  Not that Qt would allow it as noted by Jeremy.

If your QGLWidget needs events from it's parent container (e.g. minimize, dock, etc.) why can't you create partner methods in the QGLWidget for them, and call them whenever the action is performed by the parent?

Comment: That was pretty much what I thought I would have to do -  I was hoping to avoid having to wrap each displayWidget function in the container widget so that the mainWindow menu/toolbar etc could call them. And since the container can hold different types of display it also has to check what it is containing.

Comment: Interestingly though the dockwidget is designed differently, it can be inherited from any QWidget and looks more like an interface type class than a pure container.